# Use q-learning method to solve knapsack problem

Tags: python, knapsack-problem, q-learning

The question is:Sugar 1 gram for 1 dollar,cookie 7 gram for 5 dollars and ice 12 gram for 10 dollars.Now i have 29 dollars,how to buy will be the heaviest?

I have found the code on the Internet, but I don’t know how to modify it to solve my question.i don't know how to change the data to what i want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
import itertools
item = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 1],
                          [6, 2],
                          [18, 5],
                          [22, 6],
                          [28, 7]],
                    columns=['Value', 'Weight'])

actions = list(range(len(item)))
limit_W = 11
gamma = 0.9

class RLforKnapsack():
    def __init__(self, limit_W, actions):
        self.limit_W = limit_W  # maximal weight
        self.epsilon = 0.9  # e-greedy algorithm
        self.gamma = 0.9  # reward decay
        self.alpha = 0.8  # learning_rate
        self.actions = actions
        self.q_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=actions)
        self.done = False

    def check_state(self, knapsack):
        if str(knapsack) not in self.q_table.index:
            # append new state to q table
            q_table_new = pd.Series([np.NAN]*len(self.actions),
                                    index=self.q_table.columns,
                                    name=str(knapsack))
            # 0-1 knapsack
            for i in list(set(self.actions).difference(set(knapsack))):
                q_table_new[i] = 0
            self.q_table = self.q_table.append(q_table_new)

    def choose_action(self, knapsack):
        self.check_state(knapsack)
        state_action = self.q_table.loc[str(knapsack), :]
        # random state_action in case there are two or more maximum
        state_action = state_action.reindex(
                np.random.permutation(state_action.index)
                )
        if np.random.uniform() < self.epsilon:
            # choose best action
            action = state_action.idxmax()  # the first maximun
        else:
            # choose random action
            action = np.random.choice(
                    list(set(self.actions).difference(set(knapsack)))
                    )
        return action

    def greedy_action(self, knapsack):
        # testing
        # choose best action
        state_action = self.q_table.loc[str(knapsack), :]
        state_action = state_action.reindex(
                np.random.permutation(state_action.index)
                )
        action = state_action.idxmax()
        return action

    def take_action(self, knapsack, action):
        # take the item
        knapsack_ = knapsack + [action]
        knapsack_.sort()
        self.check_state(knapsack_)
        return knapsack_

    def rewardWithPenalty(self, knapsack_, action):
        # constraint
        knapsack_W = np.sum([item['Weight'][i] for i in knapsack_])
        if knapsack_W > self.limit_W:
            r = -10
            self.done = True
        else:
            r = item['Value'][action]
        return r

    def update_qvalue(self, knapsack, knapsack_, action):
        self.done = False
        reward = self.rewardWithPenalty(knapsack_, action)
        q_predict = self.q_table.loc[str(knapsack), action]
        if len(knapsack) != len(self.actions):
            q_target = reward + self.gamma * self.q_table.loc[
                    str(knapsack_), :].max()
        else:
            q_target = reward  # no item can be added
        self.q_table.loc[str(knapsack), action] += self.alpha * (
                q_target - q_predict)
        print("rl----")
        print(self.q_table)
        print("--------")
        return self.q_table, self.done


t1 = time()
plt.close('all')
RL = RLforKnapsack(limit_W=11, actions=actions)
for episode in range(100):
    print("episode--")
    print(episode)
    knapsack = []
    for step in range(5):
        print("step--")
        print(step)
        action = RL.choose_action(knapsack)
        print("action---")
        print(action)
        knapsack_ = RL.take_action(knapsack, action)
        q_table_RL, done = RL.update_qvalue(knapsack, knapsack_, action)
        knapsack = knapsack_
        if done:
        
            break
    plt.scatter(episode, q_table_RL.iloc[0, 3], c='r')
    plt.scatter(episode, q_table_RL.iloc[0, 4], c='b')
t2 = time()
plt.title([t2-t1, 'RL'])
plt.show()

# %% Policy based on q table
knapsack = []
# %%
action = RL.greedy_action(knapsack)
knapsack_ = RL.take_action(knapsack, action)
knapsack = knapsack_
np.sum([item['Weight'][i] for i in knapsack_])
print(np.sum([item['Weight'][i] for i in knapsack_]))
# %%
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. Do you understand the code you posted? What adjustments need to be done to your problem?

Comment: The content of my code is:Maximise the total value under the maximal weight constraint.

Comment: I want to change the item in the code to [1, 1],[7, 5],[12, 10], and change the limit to 29, but cause error, and i don't know why. I don't know the rest of the code.